# Getting array index out of bounds exception but don't know why?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a `split()` method that reads a file, line by line, then separates the `String`s and `Integer`s into an array that is then written to another file. I have created an array to hold each `String` called `list` and one to hold the `Integer`s called `scores`.

When I try to run my code, it reaches the second element in the `list` array which is `surname = list[1]` and then I get the error.

What I am trying to eventually do is split each element and get the average of the Integers so the original line of text would read `Mildred Bush 45 65 45 67 65` and my new line of text would read `Bush, Mildred: Final score is x.xx`.

The error happens at line 7 `surname = list[1];`

My code:

```
public void splitTest()
{
    String forename, surname, tempStr, InputFileName, OutputFileName;
    tempStr = "";
    String[] list = new String[6];
    list = tempStr.split(" ");
    forename = list[0];
    surname = list[1];
    int[] scores = new int[5];
    scores[0] = Integer.parseInt(list[2]);
    scores[1] = Integer.parseInt(list[3]);
    scores[2] = Integer.parseInt(list[4]);
    scores[3] = Integer.parseInt(list[5]);
    scores[4] = Integer.parseInt(list[6]);
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    clrscr();
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file that is to be READ (e.g. details.txt) : ");
    InputFileName = Genio.getString();
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file that is to be WRITTEN TO (e.g. newDetails.txt) : ");
    OutputFileName = Genio.getString();
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(InputFileName);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(OutputFileName);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        tempStr = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (tempStr != null) {
            System.out.println(tempStr);
            printWriter.write(tempStr+"\n");
            tempStr = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nYOUR NEW FILE DATA IS DISPLAYED ABOVE!\n\n");
        pressKey();
        bufferedReader.close();
        printWriter.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there has been a problem opening or reading from the file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred when attempting to close the file");
            }
        }
        if(printWriter != null) {
            printWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Where it says `Genio`, this a class that deals with user input.

Answer (score 3):

You initialize the `list` array with

```
list = tempStr.split(" ");
```

The size of that array can be anything. It depends on the number of spaces in `tempStr`.
You have to check the length of `list` before accessing its elements.

If you expect the input to contain a certain number of parameters, add a check :

```
list = tempStr.split(" ");
int[] scores = new int[5];
if (list.length > 6) {
    forename = list[0];
    surname = list[1];       
    scores[0] = Integer.parseInt(list[2]);
    scores[1] = Integer.parseInt(list[3]);
    scores[2] = Integer.parseInt(list[4]);
    scores[3] = Integer.parseInt(list[5]);
    scores[4] = Integer.parseInt(list[6]);
}
```

This would prevent the exception. Of course, you have to decide how to handle the situation in which the condition is false.

EDIT :

```
tempStr = "";
```

This means there would be exactly one element in `list`. I'm assuming you meant to put some actual value in this variable.

Comment: @Eran Could you explain how? I have edited my code to explain where exactly I get the error. Thanks.

Comment: @Eran Thank you. Maybe I am going about this all wrong as I don't get it :/ I'm using  `tempStr` as the variable that will read the next line in the file, which you see further down my code. I'm not sure what value I should have in `tepStr` to begin with?

Comment: @DarkBlueMullet You should only call the code that splits and parses `tempStr` after you read each line from the input file.

Comment: @Eran Please forgive the questions as I am still a beginner. So does that mean that I should only be calling `tempStr` inside the `while` loop where it says `tempStr = bufferedReader.readLine();`?